# Understanding Uncommented Sympy Code Provided as Example by Professor

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

As of right now, I am trying to learn different types of packages for python in a class. The following snippet of code was provided by my professor as an example. Is the uncommented code simply incomplete or is something happening in the background amongst all of the variables such as creating and solving a system of equations whose answer is just not listed when run? The portion I am talking about is the uncommented section as I already understand the top part. Thanks!

```
# #ball_euler
# from pylab import *
# D = 0.0245 # mˆ-1
# g = 9.8 # m/sˆ2
# y0 = 2.0
# v0 = 0.0
# time = 0.5
# dt = 0.00001
# # Variables
# n = int(time/dt)
# y = zeros(n,float)
# v = zeros(n,float)
# a = zeros(n,float)
# t = zeros(n,float)
# # Initialize
# y[0] = y0
# v[0] = v0

# # Integration loop
# for i in range(n-1):
#     a[i]=-g-D*v[i]*abs(v[i])
#     v[i+1]=v[i]+a[i]*dt
#     y[i+1]= y[i]+v[i+1]*dt
#     t[i+1] = t[i]+dt
# print (v[i+1])
# plot(t[0:i-1], a[0:i-1])
# xlabel('t [s]'); ylabel('a [m/s^2]');
# show()
# plot(t[0:i-1], v[0:i-1])
# xlabel('t [s]'); ylabel('v [m/s]');
# show()
# plot(t[0:i-1], y[0:i-1])
# xlabel('t [s]'); ylabel('y [m]');

from sympy import *
v = Function('v')
t = Symbol('t',real=True,positive=True)
g = Symbol('g',real=True,positive=True)
D = Symbol('D',real=True,positive=True)
dsolve(Derivative(v(t),t)+g-D*v(t)**2,v(t))
-(sqrt(g)*tanh(sqrt(D*g)*t))/sqrt(D)
integrate(-(sqrt(g)*tanh(sqrt(D*g)*t))/sqrt(D),t)
```

Comment: Is the top part relevant to the question? If not, take it out of the post, it just clutters it.

Comment: The question isn't very clear. We can't tell if the code is complete if you don't say what it's supposed to do.

Comment: You don't seem to be assigning the results of the functions to any variables or printing them. So you're solving the equations, but not showing it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. The correct person to explain someone else's code is *the author*. We can't read your professor's mind. Furthermore, this is **not a discussion forum**, so we can't go back and forth with you to [figure out exactly how you need it explained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797). Your professor, or perhaps a TA, can.

Comment: Sorry for the clutter. I included it because I was unsure of whether or not it mattered to the problem overall. It is supposed to numerically solve the equation as far as I know. I am not sure as to what is necessary or not, but I assumed the top was separate due to my professor's description. The class is remote and this was one of the excess materials the professor posted but never explained in any way. I was more looking to understand the "-(sqrt(g)*tanh(sqrt(D*g)*t))/sqrt(D)" and if it did anything

Comment: "and this was one of the excess materials the professor posted but never explained in any way" Does the class offer any mechanism by which you can ask the professor questions?

Comment: He may be trying to solve symbolically the same function that solved (and plotted) numerically in the commented code.  I suppose one could substitute the numeric values in the last result, and have `sympy` plot the result against `t`.

Comment: The last line integrates the line you have questions about.  I was able to plot that integral.  Decide for yourself whether that corresponds to the first part that you understand.

Answer (score -1):

In IPython with the `isympy` setup, I can post this code and get:

```
In [15]: from sympy import *
    ...: v = Function('v')
    ...: t = Symbol('t',real=True,positive=True)
    ...: g = Symbol('g',real=True,positive=True)
    ...: D = Symbol('D',real=True,positive=True)

In [16]: v,t,g,D
Out[16]: (v, t, g, D)

In [17]: dsolve(Derivative(v(t),t)+g-D*v(t)**2,v(t))
Out[17]:
```

[image: ￼]

```
In [18]: -(sqrt(g)*tanh(sqrt(D*g)*t))/sqrt(D)
Out[18]:
```

[image: ￼]

```
In [19]: integrate(-(sqrt(g)*tanh(sqrt(D*g)*t))/sqrt(D),t)
Out[19]:
```

[image: ￼]

The last 3 lines are independent, generating their own output, but nothing is saved or carried over.

[18] is just a sympy expression; basically same as the input, with a little rearranging of terms.

[19] integrates that expression.

`dsolve` in [17] is one of sympy's equation solvers, returning a value for `v(t)`.  While it has some terms in common with [18], I don't see an obvious connnection.

Normally I test `sympy` in a regular `isympy` terminal; here I am using a qt console version, and posting the formatted output required extra import of images.

```
In [24]: val.subs({D:0.0245, g:9.8})
Out[24]:
```

[image: ￼]

Using `sympy's` own `plot`, I get:

```
In [26]: val1 = val.subs({D:0.0245, g:9.8})
In [27]: plot(val1)
```

[image]

Here's the images derived from the numeric part

[image]
[image]
[image]